# Как прикруть kivy scrollview

Tags: kivy

Вообщем захотел создать простенькое приложение, так для себя в учебных целях на Kivy на Андроид. Сразу говорю начал недавно. Так вот нужно, что бы приложение можно было скролить, но как я не пытался я так и не понял как это сделать.

main.py

```
    from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder


class Container1(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Container1,self).__init__()




class MyApp(App):
    title = "Scroll view"
    def build(self):
        return Container1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

My.ky

```
<Container1>:


    BoxLayout:


            Label:
                text: 'Имя персонажа:'
                font_size: 23
                size_hint: 1, 1
                haling: 'middle'
                valing: 'left'
                text_size: self.size

            TextInput:
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 3, 0.15
                font_size: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну в документации я тоже ничего не нашел. 
Подсмотрел:

```
ScrollView:
        id: sv
        TextInput:
            id: t_input
            foreground_color: 1,1,1,1
            background_color: 0,0,0,0
            size_hint_y: None
            height: max(self.minimum_height, sv.height)
            text: 'Some text'
```

Я даже вопрос такой задал "Как до этого можно без документации дойти самостоятельно" )))

Дальше тебе документация расскажет как это все красиво сделать. 
Скрол появится когда у тебя текст бокс забьётся до конца. 
Цвета текстбокса я поменял чтобы ты смог увидеть скроллер. Он белый по дефолту.